# Finding geo location from ip address in Hive table

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I have a Hive table which has ip address. How can I find geo location such as city, zip from it?

```
hive> desc ad_data;
OK
ad_id string 
id_segment bigint 
ip string 
datecreate string 
action string 
utc_date string 
utc_hour string
```

Is there any python code that can give city, zip from ip address or hive udf with Jars?

Thanks
Rio

Comment: How did u resolve it eventually?

Answer (score -1):

there are databases available for purchase online, when you have that, just query the DB

Comment: Can someone share the Hive Jar?

Comment: I am looking for Hive UDFs Jar files.